# MVVM Light in Visual Studio 2012 shows no project templates

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, mvvm-light

I have followed guide on http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/installing/ to install MVVM light on VS 2012. I've downloaded MVVM Light Toolkit V4.1 for Visual Studio 2012 from http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/releases and after installation I cannot see any MVVM light projects when I click FILE->NEW PROJECT in VS 2012.

I choose to install binaries, templates and snippets everything by default. I have no idea what's happening.

What do I wrong? There are no errors.

My aim is to create MVVM light project with VS 2012 in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved problem by installing it manually from the source code. I've copied snipptes, templates to VS 2012 directory and it worked.

Source can be found here http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/b9bb3f49bb0e

Comment: QArea and Patrice's answers are both better.

Comment: For me it does not have any matter which is better but which is **working** I've tried this solution and it didn't work but I described how I've done it and it's working.

Comment: In my case, the other two answers did not work. The only folders located at "C:\Program Files\Laurent Bugnion (GalaSoft)\Mvvm Light Toolkit" are "Binaries" and "Snippets", so I'll need to use Robert's approach as well.

Comment: @Robert - Unfortunately, I'm not actually sure if it worked, since I ended up moving to a completely different development machine before I could test it. From there, I was able to get the templates showing by simply installing the MVVM Light Toolkit from the NuGet Package Manager (this hadn't worked properly on the original machine either). The original machine had multiple versions of Visual Studio, so I wonder if the package installer was putting them in the wrong place.

Answer (score 9):

To enable project template you have to go to Start - Programs - MVVM Light - Vsix folder and run one of the files there (I think you need MvvmLight.VS2012.vsix but read their names carefully to find the one that fits your Visual Studio edition).
If you don't have such folder - try to find it somewhere in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Laurent Bugnion (GalaSoft)\Mvvm Light Toolkit\Vsix"

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late, but check the following path:

C:\Program Files\Laurent Bugnion (GalaSoft)\Mvvm Light Toolkit\Vsix

(Start > All Programs > MvvmLight > VSIX)

You'll find Visual Studio Extensions (vsix).  Try running the VS2012.