# MVVM Light Solution cannot be found in VS 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, mvvm-light

My aim is to create a MVVM Light project with Visual Studio 2013 in C#. I have downloaded MVVM Light (v. 5.0.2) from [CodePlex](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/releases), i.e. `MvvmLight.VS2013.vsix`.

After installation I can select the templates when I create a new project. However, after creating a new MvvmLight-Project, I get an error saying that the project solution could not be found and that I should make sure my solution directory is saved. When I run the project, I get an error saying that the type or namespace "GalaSoft" could not be found.

I already saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15783746/mvvm-light-in-visual-studio-2012-shows-no-project-templates), which also covers problems with installing MVVM Light. However, it's a different issue and the solutions in this thread do not solve my problem. Did I do anything wrong?

**UPDATE:**

The exact error is

> Unable to locate the solution directory. Please ensure that the solution has been saved.

Then, when I run the project, I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'GalaSoft' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Can you share more information of the exact error encountered?

Comment: I added the exact error to my question. Sorry, it took me so long... had to install the English language pack first :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding an MVVM Light project to an existent solution works. I'm totally new to WPF and MVVM, so I didn't know that this is the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

Use NuGet, it's very easy.  See these instructions:  http://www.mvvmlight.net/installing/nuget/